# ros2cli lifecycle: shutdown transition?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed using the console command "ros2 lifecycle set *node*" I cannot force a "shutdown (5)" transition since it is not available in the transition list.
I can force the transition using the "service", why not using "lifecycle"?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302402/ros2cli-lifecycle:-shutdown-transition?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-09-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for reporting this. This is indeed a wrong in the way we currently call the lifecycle API from the command line interface.

So what's happening? The command line interface currently calls `get_available_transitions` and returns a list of all possible transitions of the state machine. However, all these transitions are actually the unique id's of each individual transition which describes the complete graph of the state machine. That's why you see transitions such as `configure_error`. This is for example the unique (internal) id of the transition from the transition state `configurING` to `error_processing`, which you are not able to trigger from the outside.
It just happens to have `configure`, `cleanup`, `activate` and `deactivate` (as the internal ID and the transitions you can trigger) as they are uniquely defined for one action to take. In the case of shutdown, there are - as you've figured out - multiple occasions where you could call it. That's why you have unique IDs for shutdown from each of these states: `unconfigured_shutdown`, `inactive_shutdown`, `active_shutdown`.

This service is nice because it lets you introspect the complete state machine, but I agree it's in fact not the list of transitions you really want. What you want is to have a list of transitions you can currently trigger on a specific state. For this we need another service which returns that list.

I ticketed the issue here: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/550

---

Originally posted by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) with karma: 643 on 2018-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1